# Sensing data Sentinel-3 time zone

Tags: remote-sensing, copernicus, sentinel-3

I have a question about sensing data time zone from https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home.
In which time zone copernicus provide for us data ?
For example on image we can see `Sensing Date` Is it CET time zone or what ? Could anyone help me with this question ?

[image]

Comment: It would be bizarre and introduce notable issues into processing workflows if it was not GMT.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans So, as I understand, they provide data in GMT time zone, aren't they ?

Answer (score 2):

As @JeffreyEvans said it's in GMT (or UTC to be more precise). This can be confirmed by checking out the time format seen in the *manifest* xml file, as well as the filename of the product.

[image]

This is the so-called [Zulu time (i.e. UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)